# Mapping columns programmatically during migration

Tags: sharepoint, migration

We have a source farm which is Moss 2007 and try to migrate it to Sharepoint 2010.

on the source farm we have two Information Lists on the top web site (category1 and category2), so in every sub web sites we have a document library which contains two custom columns col1 and col2 (among others). the data for these columns comes from category1 and category2 (for all sub web sites) which are showen as dropdownlist and every field (file) in these documnt libraries get a value form the dropdownlists.

On the target farm's Managed Metadata we have created two lists (same as source farm) targetCat1 and targetCat2.
Now I want to create an application which goes through all sub sites and goes through all Document libraries and creates new target document Library, gets data (file) from source sub site, moves it to target docuemtn library on target sub site and mapps Category1 to targetCat1, Category2 to targetCat2 for every file.

Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at partner solutions rathen than reinventing the wheel. Search for SharePoint migration to find options